# $(|z-i|+|z+i|+|z-7i|+|z+3i|)_{min}=?$ if $z\in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

I tried using this

$$|z_{1}+z_{2}+z_{3}+....+z_{n}| \leq |z_1|+|z_2|+...+|z_n|$$

to get $|z-i|+|z+i|+|z-7i|+|z+3i|=|z-i|+|z+i|+|7i-z|+|-3i-z| \geq |(z-i)+(z+i)+(7i-z)+(-3i-z)|=4$
But the official answer is 12. I found out that equality won't hold here since the numbers inside the absolute brackets can't be on the same side of origin and be collinear.

After this, I am not getting any ideas on how to reach the answer. Please help me here.

Comment: Draw a picture. You are finding the point minimizing the sum of distances to $i, - i, - 3i$, and $7i$. The minimum must be achieved on which line?

Comment: Pictorially, it seems like the imaginary axis.

Comment: Correct, can you justify why? And then can you justify which point minimizes the distance on it? (I can help as you need it, I just want you to try first)

Comment: As a hint, use collinearity and a bit of geometric intuition in your justification for the solution being on the imaginary axis, and then guess the right point via symmetry, and then justify based on which terms change the most as you move the point around the imaginary axis.

Comment: Taking any point $z$ other than that on the imaginary axis, creates two triangles of sides

Comment: That's exactly the right idea! (and could be formalized via something like the triangle inequality using the fact all the points are collinear along the imaginary axis if you needed to write up a proof.) Now try to use symmetry to figure out which point on the imaginary axis minimizes distance.

Comment: 0 seems to approzimate the symmetry.

Comment: But I can take any point between i and -i right?

Comment: You're absolutely right, any point between $-i$ and $i$ will work. $0$ is indeed what I had in mind via symmetry, but the additional distance from moving up or down a bit cancels out, as long as don't pass beyond $i$ or $-i$. Anything beyond that increases the distance, so you're done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, since $i,-i,7i,-3i$ are colinear, you can solve this problem as if it was on the real line and find the minimum of

$$f(x) = |x+3| + |x+1| + |x-1| + |x-7|$$

On $]-\infty,-3]$ the function is decreasing since it is something like $-4x+k$

On $[-3,-1]$ the function is decreasing since it is something like $-2x+k$

On $[-1,1]$ it is constant and it increases after

The minimum of $f$ is given by $$f(1) = 12$$

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse $|-\alpha| = |\alpha|$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, so write $$|z-7i| = |-z+7i|$$ and $$|z-i| = |-z+i|$$ and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

The average of $i, -i, 7i, -3i$ is
$$ \frac{i+(-i)+7i+(-3i)}{4}=i $$
and then
$$ (|z-i|+|z+i|+|z-7i|+|z+3i|)_{min}=(|z-i|+|z+i|+|z-7i|+|z+3i|)\bigg|_{z=i}=2+6+4=12.$$

Comment: This isn't a correct solution technique. Consider minimizing $|z+i| + |z+2i| + |z+3i| + |z-102i|$. Then the average is $\frac{102i -i - 2i - 3i}{4} = 24i$, yielding a value of $|24i+i| + |24i+2i| + |24i+3i| + |24i-102i| = 156$, while just taking $z = 0$ yields a value of $108$. It just happens that all the values were close enough in this case that your average yielded something in the range $[-i, i]$ where the minimum is achieved, but this won't always happen if the numbers are changed.